# Agenda not running the job after server restart - NodeJS, Express

Tags: node.js, express, agenda

I have a Node-Express application, in which I have got the logic to create Agenda jobs dynamically.

I am following the documentation of [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda#example-project-structure), and have got similar project structure.

The main difference is that, in the controller action, I am defining a new job, instead of calling `agenda.now()`

This is my controller action

```
const createNewJob = (req, res, next) => {
  const {username, type} = req.body;

  const jobName = username + type;

  agenda.define(jobName, async job => {
    console.log('Running new job');
  });
  
  agenda.every('2 minutes', jobName);
}
```

This works fine and runs the job every 2 minutes as long as the server is running. But, if the server has been restarted, the job doesn't trigger even if the nextRunAt is in future.

I can see that the job is NOT locked in DB. I tried the solution mentioned in [this repo](https://github.com/farhan711/task-scheduling/blob/master/jobs/agenda.js) too. That didn't work either.

Also, tried adding agenda.start() during server startup (after the call to connect to MongoDB). No luck with that too.

```
agenda.on("ready", function() {
  agenda.start();
  console.log('Starting agenda...');
});
```

Would be great if anyone can suggest what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.